# HTML Table : Want to design a table strucutre like this

Tags: html-table

I have this table structure

[image: table structure]

I am new to table structure. I want to design the table like in the image. the first column should have bigger width then the other and

```css
table{
  background: white;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 60px auto;
  border-spacing: 0;

}

th{
  border-bottom: 2px yellow solid;
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table>

    <tr>
      <th width="75%" align="left" style="padding-left:25px;">
        Work Category
      </th>
      <th>
        Qty
      </th>
      <th>
        Unit/Price
      </th>
      <th>
        Price
      </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th width="75%" align="left" style="padding-left:25px;">

      </th>
      <th>

      </th>
      <th>

      </th>
      <th>

      </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th width="75%" align="left" style="padding-left:25px;">

      </th>
      <th>

      </th>
      <th>

      </th>
      <th>

      </th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th width="75%" align="left" style="padding-left:25px;">

      </th>
      <th>

      </th>
      <th>

      </th>
      <th>
        
      </th>
    </tr>


    <tr>
      <th width="75%" align="left" style="padding-left:25px;">

      </th>
      <th>

      </th>
      <th>

      </th>
      <th>

      </th>
    </tr>



  </table>
```

I don't know how to write only last 2 column i.e subtotal and Rs.

Any help would be great.

Thank You.

Comment: Why haven't you used `colspan`?

Comment: i m new to html table structure. so i don't know how to use it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here it is. In case of any question, please ask in the comments.

```css
table{
                background: white;
                width: 85%;
                margin: 60px auto;
                border-spacing: 0;
            }
            table, tr, th, td{                
                border: 2px yellow solid;
            }

            th, td{
                height: 30px;
                font-size: 12px;
                display: table-cell;
                vertical-align: bottom;
                padding-bottom: 2px;
            }

            .col1{
                width: 60%;
            }
            .col2{
                width: 9%;
            }
            .col3{
                width: 12%;
            }
            .col4{
                width: 19%;
            }
```

```html
<table>
            <tr>
                <th class="col1">Work Category</th>
                <th class="col2">QTY</th>
                <th class="col3">Unit/Price</th>
                <th class="col4">Price</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1"></td>
                <td class="col2"></td>
                <td class="col3"></td>
                <td class="col4"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="col1" style="background-color: yellow"></td>
                <td class="col2" colspan="2"></td>
                <td class="col4"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

TH are used for table headers, so instead for any cells that contain data use TD then if you need to combine cells, use rowspan and colspan, you can familiarize yourself with them using the resources below:

Rowspan article W3Schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_rowspan.asp

Colspan Article W3Schools:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_colspan.asp

If you want to add style to a column I would suggest assigning a class and then applying that style to the particular class, you can find that information on W3Schools explained quite well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

HTML

```
<table>
<tr>
  <th align="left">
    Work Category
  </th>
  <th>
    Qty
  </th>
  <th>
    Unit/Price
  </th>
  <th>
    Price
  </th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="left">
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="left">
  </td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td align="left">
  </td>
  <td colspan="2"></td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
```

CSS

```
table{
  background: white;
  width: 85%;
  margin: 60px auto;
  /*border-spacing: 0;*/
  border-collapse:collapse;
}

th, td{
  height: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  padding-bottom: 2px;
  border: 2px solid yellow;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

table th:first-child{
  width: 60%;
}

table th{
  width: 7%;
}

table th:last-child{
  width: 20%;
}
```